# MS Excel conditional formatting range changes after editing cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet in MS Excel 2010 with conditional formatting applied to the selected range as on the screenshot:
[image: right CF range].

But if I edit connected cells, CF immediatly applies to some of them in very strange manner:
[image: CF range after editing some cells].

What is going on and how can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: What are your "connected cells" and what are your conditional formatting rules?

Comment: @AlexisOlson connected cells are filled with "1" on second screenshot. CF rules aren't related to issue. They are like "IF(F8 <> C8)" and two similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. After many attempts seeking any rule where CF applies and where doesn't and hours in forums, I've finally found a checkbox in options->advanced "extend data range formats and formulas" which affected the issue.

Comment: Didn't seem to help, I'm still getting the conditional formatting ranges changing after I unchecked "extend data range formats and formulas"